# Abstract Factory with heterogenous components

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

While the Abstract Factory claims to create families of products it seems that it isn't usable when the family being created isn't homogenous in its component composition. By this it is meant that while Abs Factory is good when each component can vary in its implementation, unfortunately each concrete factory produces a family comprised of all the same type of components. Thus each family has same components which vary only in the implementation of each component. I wish not to include some components when a component does not apply. I don't want to include component C in Fac4 but I'm forced to do so. How can I have a flexible factory where I'm not forced to include every component?  Keep in mind that I would like to use the base in client code to take advantage of polymorphism.

To this end... every example I find uses examples like PizzaFactory or CarFactory... but these examples all assume that every pizza has cheese or every car has a stereo.  Only the type of cheese or stereo varies. I'm forced to return NULL for items that don't apply. Very dirty to include functions that don't apply or make sense.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class IA
{
public:
    virtual ~IA() {cout << "IA::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};
class A1 : public IA
{
public:
    A1() {cout << "A1::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~A1() {cout << "A1::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() {cout << "A1::foo()" << endl;}
    virtual void bar() {cout << "A1::bar()" << endl;}
};
class A2 : public IA
{
public:
    A2() {cout << "A2::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~A2() {cout << "A2::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() {cout << "A2::foo()" << endl;}
    virtual void bar() {cout << "A2::bar()" << endl;}
};

class IB
{
public:
    virtual ~IB() {cout << "IB::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};
class B1 : public IB
{
public:
    B1() {cout << "B1::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~B1() {cout << "B1::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() {cout << "B1::foo()" << endl;}
    virtual void bar() {cout << "B1::bar()" << endl;}
};
class B2 : public IB
{
public:
    B2() {cout << "B2::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~B2() {cout << "B2::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() {cout << "B2::foo()" << endl;}
    virtual void bar() {cout << "B2::bar()" << endl;}
};

class IC
{
public:
    virtual ~IC() {cout << "IC::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};
class C1 : public IC
{
public:
    C1() {cout << "C1::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~C1() {cout << "C1::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() {cout << "C1::foo()" << endl;}
    virtual void bar() {cout << "C1::bar()" << endl;}
};
class C2 : public IC
{
public:
    C2() {cout << "C2::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~C2() {cout << "C2::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() {cout << "C2::foo()" << endl;}
    virtual void bar() {cout << "C2::bar()" << endl;}
};
class C3 : public IC
{
public:
    C3() {cout << "C3::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~C3() {cout << "C3::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual void foo() {cout << "C3::foo()" << endl;}
    virtual void bar() {cout << "C3::bar()" << endl;}
    void boo() {cout << "C3::boo()" << endl;}
};

class IFac
{
public:
    virtual ~IFac() {cout << "IFac::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual IA* createA() = 0;
    virtual IB* createB() = 0;
    virtual IC* createC() = 0;
};
//This product uses only 1st gen components ... OK
class Fac1 : public IFac
{
public:
    Fac1() {cout << "Fac1::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~Fac1() {cout << "Fac1::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual IA* createA() {return new A1;}
    virtual IB* createB() {return new B1;}
    virtual IC* createC() {return new C1;}
};
//This product uses only 2nd gen components ... OK
class Fac2 : public IFac
{
public:
    Fac2() {cout << "Fac2::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~Fac2() {cout << "Fac2::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual IA* createA() {return new A2;}
    virtual IB* createB() {return new B2;}
    virtual IC* createC() {return new C2;}
};
//This product uses components from 3 generations ... OK
class Fac3 : public IFac
{
public:
    Fac3() {cout << "Fac3::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~Fac3() {cout << "Fac3::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual IA* createA() {return new A1;}
    virtual IB* createB() {return new B2;}
    virtual IC* createC() {return new C3;}
};
//This product uses components from 2 generations but not all components apply to product ... HOW?
class Fac4 : public IFac
{
public:
    Fac4() {cout << "Fac4::ctor()" << endl;}
    virtual ~Fac4() {cout << "Fac4::dtor()" << endl;}
    virtual IA* createA() {return new A1;}
    virtual IB* createB() {return new B2;}
    virtual IC* createC() {return nullptr;}  //component does not apply but forced to include!!!
};


int main()
{
        IFac* fac = new Fac4;
        IA* a = fac->createA();
        a->foo();
        a->bar();
        delete a;
        IB* b = fac->createB();
        b->foo();
        b->bar();
        delete b;

        //Want to avoid seeing this function because it does not apply.
        //Should not be able to see and call createC()
        IC* c = fac->createC();
        if(c == nullptr)
            cout << "C does not apply" << endl;
        else
        {
            c->foo();
            c->bar();
            delete c;
        }

        delete fac;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Abstract factories have to respect Liskov's substitution principle like any other abstract construct. Uses an abstract factory, it needs to be able to handle any and all realisation of it. So either the user of the abstract factory does not need `createC()`, in which case it does not belong in the interface, or it does and all subclasses MUST implement it. There's no in-between.

Comment: Yet not all cars have a stereo and not all pizzas have meat.  If Abs Factory can't handle this use-case which OOP creational pattern does?  In the example above think of A, B, C as 3 different components.  Ex. A1,A2,A3 refer to generation of (newer model).  I want to have creation of a mix of components not just so I have generational flexibility but also flexibility with respect to composition.  Favouring composition over inheritance.  It seems Abs Factory throws compositional flexibility out the window.  Is there a pattern or an mod to Abs Factory that allows for flexible composition?

Comment: An abstract factory only produces the interface common to all possible objects. If "cheese" is not part of the interface common to all pizzas, then "cheese" can be demoted to being an implementation detail of the pizza, and not part of the universal "pizza" interface anymore.

Comment: I hear you...but if cheese is optional then so are all the other toppings.  Thus we may as well throw away the base as useless.  In that sense, there is nothing guaranteed to be in common for pizza.  I'm sure we can say same for most things.  It seems Abs Fact boxes you in just like inheritance.  This is why it is not ideal to talk about pizza per say...and rather focus on conceptual objects like A,B,C.  Since we are told to favour composition over inheritance, there must be a creational pattern that can actually make use of the main benefit of composition (picking and choosing what to have).

Comment: Based on the description here, an Abstract Factory is not what you want. Have you considered a Builder?

Comment: @jaco0646 Yes, Abs Fac is inflexible when it comes to composition. That was my point.  I was hoping there was some way to handle the null situation better or that there may be a better design pattern for my needs.  Keeping with the core of the non-trivial example I posted with sub-products A,B,C and each such having concrete or generational implementations (A1,A2...)... I want to construct products that not only have sub-comp generational flexibility but also compositional flexibility for which sub-product actually applies to the product being produced.  I don't believe builder can do this.

Comment: @javo0646 It would be interesting if someone can post an example of how builder can solve this problem using the A,B,C objs I posted and their respective concrete implementations above.  Rather than some trivial string example that hides the usage issues encountered when assembling non heterogenous objs into a product.  The solution should use the SOLID principles.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you have the correct understanding.

The abstract factory creates objects that are derived from a common base object.

Then, if applied, the implementation is rather simple.

See the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```